# Python: count word lenth in site name

Tags: python

Got stuck with a part of the python script. For example I got 2 domain names like:

- domain.com
- new.domain1.us

is it possible to count word lenght of every word, splited with dot and put the lenght in brackets before every word like:

- (6)domain(3)com
- (3)new(7)domain1(2)us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = 'domain.com'
answer = ''
for x in string.split('.'):
    answer += '(' + str(len(x)) + ')' + x
print(answer)
```

Comment: `''.join('({}){}'.format(len(x), x) for x in string.split('.'))`

Comment: @AvihooMamka I missed a `)`  in `str()` now I updated

Comment: I deleted my comment. not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The method `split()` will split the string at the given char into an array of strings.

`len()` will return you the length of the given string/array/...

With these two functions you can solve your problem:

```
domain = "www.google.de"
split_domain = domain.split('.')

domain_with_len = ""
for part in split_domain:
    domain_with_len += "(" + str(len(part)) + ")" + part
```

if you print the `domain_with_len` you get the following result:

```
(3)www(6)google(2)de
```